# Listar contenido de un documento txt

Tags: c#

Tengo que listar por nombre y raza de animales sacados de un txt, no consigo que se formen solo que salgan todos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace animales
{
    class Program
     {

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
               List<string> nombre= new List<string>();
               List<string> tipoAnimal= new List<string>();


             using (StreamReader leer = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ssnak\Desktop\animales\animales.txt"))
             {
                while(!leer.EndOfStream)
                {            
                    string x= leer.ReadLine();                  
                   nombre.Add(x);      

                } 
                foreach(string j in nombre)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                }
                 Console.ReadKey();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Esto es lo que quiero listar por nombres o por tipo en contenido txt, están separados por comas y he de buscar por nombre o por tipo de animal y listarlos:

```
roco,perro
pepu,gato
carlos,guacamayo
```

Comment: Cuando haces `nombre.Add(x);` se te añade la línea entera a la lista ¿verdad? por ejemplo `"roco,perro"` o `"Isidoro,gato"`.

Comment: si salen todos junto sin separarse

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que separar las cadenas tras leerlas:

```
var x = leer.ReadLine().Split(',');
```

Una vez tienes las cadenas separadas, puedes guardarlas por separado:

```
nombre.add(x[0]);
tipoAnimal.add(x[1]);
```

Posteriormente, para buscar, usa [`IndexOf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_IndexOf__0_):

```
var indice = nombre.IndexOf(nombre);

if (indice == -1)
    Console.WriteLine(nombre + " no se encontró");
else
    Console.WriteLine(nombre + " es un " + tipoAnimal[indice]);
```

Comment: string x = leer.ReadLine().Split(","),  aqui me pone este error: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string[]' en 'string'

Comment: @bssm perdón, tenía que ser `var x = leer.ReadLine().Split(',');`, ya lo he corregido en la respuesta.

Comment: var indice = nombre.IndexOf(nombre);

if (indice == -1)
    Console.WriteLine(nombre + " no se encontró");
else
    Console.WriteLine(nombre + " es un " + tipoAnimal[indice]); ¿en que parte pongo esto?

Comment: @bssm en tu pregunta escribiste "*he de buscar por nombre o por tipo de animal*". Yo te puse un ejemplo de cómo buscar por nombre, el dónde lo pongas es cosa tuya.

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejaria no trabajes los datos por separado sino que uses `Programacion Orientada a Objetos` con lo cual defines una clases para mapear con las filas del archivo

Entonces defines una class como ser

```
public class Animal{
   public string nombre {get;set;}
   public string raza {get;set;}
}
```

Y el procesar el archivo usarias

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> animales= new List<Animal>();

        string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ssnak\Desktop\animales\animales.txt");


        foreach(string linea in lineas)
        {
            string[] partes = linea.Split(',');

            Animal animal = new Animal()
            animal.nombre = partes[0];
            animal.raza = partes[1];
            animales.Add(animal);
        }

        foreach(Animal animal in animales)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre:{0} Razo:{1}", animal.nombre, animal.raza);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

de esta forma aprendes un poco de POO con el uso de clases que dejan el codigo mucho mas prolijo al relacionar los datos en objetos